# ROS Service global name not defined

Tags: ros-melodic, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make my node a ROS service which gets triggered when it receives boolean value of true, thus I have added the following to its constructor:

```
self.imgproc_srv = rospy.Service("/perception/request_detection", RequestDetection, self.detection_processor_srv)
```

here is the callback:

```
def detection_processor_srv(self, req): 
         print("It works!")
   return
```

And of course, I have the file `RequestDetection.srv` as:

```
bool detection_requested # our trigger to initiate the visual detection
```

and I imported this in my script as:

```
from common.srv import *
```

which is where I plan to keep the services.

Needless to say, I did `catkin_make` as well, after all this.

Yet I receive:

`NameError: global name 'RequestDetection' is not defined`

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313148/ros-service-global-name-not-defined/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you haven't defined your service properly, I would have expected you to get an error when you try and catkin_make this.

If you look at the [tutorial on messages and services](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_rossrv), you can see that a service needs to define both the request and response parts separated by there hyphens `---` like the example shown there:

```
int64 a
int64 b
---
int64 sum
```

As also described in the tutorial above you need to setup your CMakeLists.txt file to make sure that this service is built too.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-01-18**:
If I only want to call this service and not expect anything in return, the parts above `---` are not required, right? I noticed since I won't expect anything, it should now work as it is like in my code?

EDIT: It was the CMakeLists.txt ,now it works.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-18**:
I see. Glad you got this working.